# Do my people need a job in order to pay taxes?

Tags: dragons-of-atlantis

My city in Dragons of Atlantis has steadily been growing and I now have a population of 12000.

[image]

But because I don't have a huge army yet and my resource buildings only provide labor to about 3000 of them, I have about an idle population of 9000.

Now I'm wondering, **does creating more jobs (thus reducing the unemployment) help raise my hourly gold income rate or is this just based on the raw population?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My gold's hourly rate went up from 2448 to 2526 when I upgraded one of my Homes, which increased my population with ~500.

[image]

Creating 100 more jobs on the other hand had no effect on my income. So its clear:

**No. You just need the people in your city to pay taxes.**

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to increase your gold production, you need to raise your taxes to just under 50% of your total available percentage.  So, if you have 102%, ~50/51% taxes and 51/52% happiness is maximum output of gold, and stable level of happiness.  As you upgrade your theater, you will be able to increase your taxes always rounding down from 50% of total.. So, at one point, iirc, you have 115% total to divide, and maximum profit/stability is a 57% tax & 58% happy..